# JavaScript do not escape \ character?

Tags: javascript

I'm building a query for YQL, and I've ran into a dumb issue. I wont be pasting in the entire query as there is no need, just the part I'm having the issue with:

```
var query = encodeURI("... and xpath='//div[@class=\\'body bodySign\\']/p' ...")';
```

As you may notice, I've added two `\` characters, it is need for the actual query. I'm using multi queries, and I need to double esacpe the `'` character in order for them to parse correctly inside YQL.

But JavaScript escapes the `\` character. It doesn't matter how many `\` I add (to "escape" to following `\` character) I still get left with only one `\` in my query.

How do I keep multiple `\` characters without them escaping each other?

Thanks

Comment: So you want to end up with `[@class=\\'body bodySign\\']` ?

Comment: Backslash only escapes the following character, so \\ = \, \\\\ = \\, etc.   `encodeURI("\\1\\2\\\\3")` gives `"%5C1%5C2%5C%5C3"`

Comment: If you want one backslash in your query, you need ``\\`` in your string (you need to escape the backslash). If you want two, you need ``\\\\``.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
var query = encodeURI("... and xpath='//div[@class=\\\\'body bodySign\\\\']/p' ...")';
```

For example, hit F12 and look at the output of `console.log("\\\\")`.